Backpack installation fails at the migrate step
I've been unable to install Backpack to my app (via php artisan backpack:install) so opted for the manual approach.  However, I get the same error message:
php artisan migrate

ErrorException

Array to string conversion

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:163
159▕      \* @return bool
160▕      \*/
161▕     public function hasTable($table)
162▕     {
➜ 163▕         $table = $this->connection->getTablePrefix().$table;
164▕
165▕         foreach ($this->getTables(false) as $value) {
166▕             if (strtolower($table) === strtolower($value['name'])) {
167▕                 return true;

      +22 vendor frames 

23  artisan:14
Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))\

My setup versions are:
PHP 8.3.9
Laravel 10.48.16.0
Backpack/crud: 6.7.21
mySQL: 8.3.0

The .env file has the correct database name listed.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Bayne

I just tried the installation via php artisan backpack:install on the Laravel version that you are using, and it is working smoothly. No issue I can reproduce.
The error you shared doesn't look Backpack related. I suspect there is something on your end that needs to be fixed.

